# How to run a function named in a variable?

Tags: python, function

I want to run a function and the name of that function is the value of a variable. So if the `variable == "Hello"` it would run the function `Hello()`. the variable is from a certain cell in an excel document (I just thought I would add that).

I have tried using `eval()` but that seems to not work when the function is more then just output of text.

```
this = sheet["B"+str(row)].value 
eval(function+"()")
```

I want it just to run the function but the shell just skips right over - `eval(this+"()")`  - so I am not sure what is actually happening.

Comment: Use a *dictionary* don't dynamically evaluate variables

Answer (score 2):

You could run the function using `eval()` as:

```
eval(variable)()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `globals()` function returns a dictionary representing the current scope, so `globals()[this]` gives a reference to the function, and `globals()[this]()` will call it with no arguments.

This is a bit safer than `eval` because it won't execute arbitrary code (although still risky on untrusted input).

Comment: Globals gives you the modules *global scope* not the current scope, which would be `locals`

Comment: I assumed that the functions that should be called are defined in module scope (top level), not as inner functions of the current function, yes.

Answer (score 0):

return the function by name using the locals variable, check for it, verify it is actually callable then run it.

```
def test_func():
    print("In test function")

func_name = "test_func"

if func_name in locals() and callable(locals()[func_name]):
    locals()[func_name]()
```

output

```
In test function
```

As mentioned by Thomas, this can also be done using global() rather than locals() if the function is in the global name space. In addition if you would like to check for a method in a class, and call that instead you'll need to use the [hasattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) function.

Comment: thank you, I did this and i can tell it is running the first line of the fun_name function but that is all??  i have also tried globals()